# is it possible to capture output of top -c -n1 -b into a text file - but preserve the full output ( i.e not truncated at right side) via shell

Tags: linux, top, capture

I used `top -c -n1 -b | tail -18 >  topout.txt`  successfully.

the `topout.txt` shows me full output of process names/command used.

But - once I copy this line of code in a .sh file and run via `crontab` or manually - the output is ALWAYS truncated i.e instead of full process entry like "oracle_myprodbrac1.."  it shows me  oracle_myp+.."  no matter how I code it.

I have tried appended to the shell logfile ( created in `cron` using
`shell_name.sh >  shell_name.log  2>&1`  )  but it ALWAYS seems to truncate RHS part.

eg:

```
Top 10 processes during this load ..
Warning! pddb1-nnvwv1 load average exceeds 25 - is 25
age: 25.35, 23.93, 19.84
Tasks: 4855 total,  34 running, 4819 sleeping,   0 stopped,   2 zombie
%Cpu(s): 79.7 us,  8.9 sy,  0.0 ni,  9.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.7 si,  0.2 st KiB Mem : 74261747+total, 17263593+free, 43575846+used, 13422308+buff/cache
KiB Swap: 16777212 total, 16768548 free,     8664 used. 28589158+avail Mem 

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 59924 oracle    20   0   96.3g 469296  98688 R  84.6  0.1   0:44.51 oracleGEC+
 62677 oracle    20   0   96.3g 469428  98824 R  78.8  0.1   0:44.41 oracleGEC+
 68076 oracle    20   0   96.3g 469616  98980 R  78.8  0.1   0:41.54 oracleGEC+
158224 oracle    20   0  102.1g 125592 113388 R  78.8  0.0 452:22.63 oracleGEC+
```

When I run the same from $ prompt - it shows me complete output.;
I can spool it to a file topout.txt, from $prompt  - I get the full output.

When I run it from cron / shell script - I see truncated output like above.

Answer (score 0):

From [`man 1 top`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/procps/top.1.en.html):

> `-w`  `:Output-width-override as:`  `-w [ number ]`
>
> In Batch mode, when used without an argument top will format output using the `COLUMNS=` and `LINES=` environment variables, if set. Otherwise, width will be fixed at the maximum 512 columns. With an argument, output width can be decreased or increased (up to 512) but the number of rows is considered unlimited.
>
> In normal display mode, when used without an argument top will attempt to format output using the `COLUMNS=` and `LINES=` environment variables, if set. With an argument, output width can only be decreased, not increased. Whether using environment variables or an argument with `-w`, when not in Batch mode actual terminal dimensions can never be exceeded.
>
> Note: Without the use of this command-line option, output width is always based on the terminal at which top was invoked whether or not in Batch mode.

It's convoluted and not entirely clear to me. E.g. it's not clear if "up to 512" applies to the case where `COLUMNS=` is set. My tests indicate that yes, the maximum whatsoever is 512 (= 511 + newline character).

I guess you cannot overcome this without modifying `top`. Use `-w 512`. Very long commands will be truncated, so it's not exactly what you requested. On the other hand you called the output observed in an interactive shell "full output" and it couldn't contain lines longer than 512; so maybe 512 will be enough for you.

Even if you encounter truncated lines sometimes, 512 will be significantly better than 80 (or so) you were getting from the cron job until now.